# Permission denied when uploading file

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, file-permissions, centos7

when i'm uploading file it shows

"failed to open stream: Permission denied"

i given **777** permission to file destination directory **/tmp** directory also **777** permission i given even i assigned apache user to /tmp and destination directory i not knowing where is the actual problem, i am running **Amazon Aws centos 7 architecture with php 5.4** i am having gd librarary and all basic require extension for uploading image...

Comment: First, You should not apply **777** permissions to files and folders, Second you should apply read and write permissions to the folder that you want the files upload to and not the **tmp** directory.

Comment: What does this have to do with image processing?  You have trouble uploading files - this is independent on the type of file itself (i.e. images).

Answer (score 2):

Most probably your server has selinux enabled. [Security Enhanced Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) provides enhanced hardening against attacks, but requires more administrative effort.

If your file/directory attributes are followed by a dot there are extended selinux attributes available:

```
[root@www tmp]# ls -ld
drwxrwxrwt. 14 root root 4096 May  4 08:45 .
          ^-- this dot means: there are more selinux attributes
```

To show the extended attributes you can use the `-Z` parameter:

```
[root@www tmp]# ls -Zd
drwxrwxrwt. root root system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0       .
```

Of course you can just disable selinux, but I wouldn't recommend it. To allow the webserver to write into a directory you can use the `chcon` command:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /path/to/directory
```